# How do you change a function name inside a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I want to change the function name inside of a for loop to something like this.

```
<script>
for (var x=1;x<10;x++){
function name_x(){
   code
}
</script>
```

So, 10 functions are produced with the names name_1, name_2 etc.

Thanks

Edit:

This is what I need a for loop around to create 5 functions id_1, id_2, id_3, id_4, id_5

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function id_1(a){
var id = document.getElementById(a);
if (id.innerHTML==="innerHTML2"){
    id.innerHTML="innerHTML1";
}
else if (id.innerHTML==="innerHTML1"){
    id.innerHTML="innerHTML2";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="id1" href="javascript:id_1('id')">innerHTML1</a>
<a id="id2" href="javascript:id_2('id')">innerHTML1</a>
<a id="id3" href="javascript:id_3('id')">innerHTML1</a>
<a id="id4" href="javascript:id_4('id')">innerHTML1</a>
<a id="id5" href="javascript:id_5('id')">innerHTML1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do u wanna do this? What will you do after creating these 10 functions?

Comment: Generating lots of similarly-named function names seems to be a pretty strong code smell.  Can you back up a little and explain the bigger picture of what you're trying to accomplish?  There's probably a better way with, say, arrays.

Comment: Well, what I am trying to accomplish is this. When I click on a link, it corresponds to a function and I want each function to do something differently. So if I have 10 links, I want 10 functions.

Comment: @user2145975: Why don't you use anonymous functions?

Comment: @user2145975: If the 10 links do 10 completely different things, then give them 10 different sensible names corresponding to their behavior.  If they are very similar and differ in a way that depends, say on the index number, then have all 10 links call the exact same function, and handle the differences with control flow logic and function arguments.  For example, you can call `handleLink(this)` to pass a reference to the source link, and do slightly different processing based on which link was clicked.

Comment: Unless you've got a very, very specific reason for this, I'd suggest that there's got to be a better way. Can you put closures in an array? Can you use the same function over again, and just pass in different arguments? How little code is changing that you can get away with writing functions as-is, and just changing the name in a loop? It appears that there would be a neater solution in half a dozen directions, if that's the case...

Comment: Is this actual code? There are many things wrong with this small snippet, for example your IDs aren't unique. I believe your problem could be handled with some classes and a simple for-loop, but that's for another day.

Answer (score 3):

This looks pretty nefarious, but if you're in a browser you could use `window` as the global object.  Otherwise, define some object to house the methods:

```
var obj = {}, x;
for (x = 1; x < 10; x++) {
    obj['name_' + x]() { /* code */ }
}
```

Then you can call via `obj.name_1()` or `obj['name_1']()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an *array* of functions instead:

```
var fs = [];
for (var x = 1; x < 10; x++){
    fs.push( function() {
       /* code */
    });
}
fs[1](); // call second function
```

You could use an object instead, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: +1 This is a good idea; but it is incorrect to say "No" to the question of whether the OP's request can be done, as @ExplosionPills has demonstrated.

Comment: Removed the wrong statement. I forget sometimes that you can actually modify `window` for some interesting things.

Comment: @user2145975: Add your tries (actual code!) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have code that should apply directly to the link you clicked on, you can pass a reference to the link using `this`.  Also, the javascript code will need to be placed in `onclick`, not `href`.  If you need an `href` value to make it appear like a link, you can use `#`:

```
<a id="id1" href="#" onclick="javascript:swapContents(this);">innerHTML1</a>
```

Then you can use the argument passed in as a reference to the element (it is a good programming practice to use meaningful function names, so I've renamed the function to `swapContents`):

```
function swapContents(el){
    if (el.innerHTML === "innerHTML2"){
        el.innerHTML = "innerHTML1";
    } else if (el.innerHTML === "innerHTML1"){
        el.innerHTML = "innerHTML2";
    }
}
```

Also, all elements should have a unique `id` value according to the HTML spec.  If you want them to be unified in some way, give them the same `class` or `name`, or a custom made-up attribute:

```
<a id="id1" class="id" href="#" onclick="javascript:swapContents(this);">innerHTML1</a>
<a id="id2" class="id" href="#" onclick="javascript:swapContents(this);">innerHTML1</a>
<a id="id3" class="id" href="#" onclick="javascript:swapContents(this);">innerHTML1</a>
<a id="id4" class="id" href="#" onclick="javascript:swapContents(this);">innerHTML1</a>
<a id="id5" class="id" href="#" onclick="javascript:swapContents(this);">innerHTML1</a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V6yG9/

Comment: this makes sense thank you, but what I if I don't want it to redirect the url (adding the #).

Comment: @user2145975: The `#` url has no effect, that's why it's generally used for javascript-only links.  If you don't like that it adds `#` to the end of your current url, you can use `href="javascript:;"` instead, which is another no-op url: http://jsfiddle.net/V6yG9/1/

Comment: What if I want to have each of those links do something differently? For instance $.get('code1.php') for one and $.get('code2.php') for another